# Using openEntityManagerInView still getting "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to return one of my entities to a JSP page but getting the following error "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role". I have added the openEntityManagerInView filter(assuming it would allow the entity manager to stay open in the view?) but still getting this error.

My application is configured using java config no xml.

Below is my dispatcher servelet. You can see i have added the openEntityManagerInView filter.

Any ideas why this is? I have checked similar questions on stackoverflow and have had no luck to the solutions provided.

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    registerOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter(servletContext);
    super.onStartup(servletContext);

}

private void registerOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
    OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter viewFilter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
    viewFilter.setEntityManagerFactoryBeanName("entityManagerFactory");
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter("openEntityManagerInView",
            new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter());
    registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{Config.class, SecurityConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
```

}

Below is the entity in question. I've omitted the getters and setters.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "film")
public class Film {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "film_id")
private int filmId;
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
@Column(name = "release_year")
private int releaseYear;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "language_id")
private Language language;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "original_language_id")
private Language originalLanguage;
@Column(name = "rental_duration")
private int rentalDuration;
@Column(name = "rental_rate")
private double rentalRate;
@Column(name = "length")
private int length;
@Column(name = " replacement_cost")
private double replacementCost;
@Column(name = "rating")
private String rating;
@Column(name = "special_features")
private String specialFeatures;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "last_update")
private Date lastUpdate;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "film", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Inventory> inventories;

.........
}
```

Below is my config for my JPA stuff.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {

@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    HibernateJpaDialect hibernateJpaDialect = new HibernateJpaDialect();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
    emf.setPackagesToScan("com");
    emf.setJpaDialect(hibernateJpaDialect);
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter);
    /* Map<String,String> props = new HashMap<>();
     props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
     emf.setJpaPropertyMap(props);*/
    emf.afterPropertiesSet();
    return emf.getObject();
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException {
    JpaTransactionManager jtm
            = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jtm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    jtm.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return jtm;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
    dds.setUsername("username");
    dds.setPassword("password");
    return dds;
}

}
```

Below is my web config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com")
public class WebConfig {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    vr.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    vr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    vr.setSuffix(".jsp");
    vr.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    return vr;
}

}
```

Below is my security config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureAuthenticationManagerBuilder(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
     .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
     .usernameParameter("username")
     .passwordParameter("password")
     .defaultSuccessUrl("/index", true).failureUrl("/login?error")
     .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check");

}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/login");
}

}
```

My Dao class below.

```
@Repository
public class FilmDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Film getFilm(int filmId) {
        Film film = em.find(Film.class, filmId);
        return film;
    }

}
```

Service class below which is called by my controllers.

```
@Service
public class FilmService {

    @Autowired
    private FilmDao filmDao;

   @Transactional
    public Film getFilm(int filmId) {
        Film film = filmDao.getFilm(filmId);
        return film;
    }

}
```

Stack trace below.

```
14:48:30,416 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-6) UT005023: Exception handling request to /test-app/WEB-INF/jsp/update_inventory.jsp: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.jm.sakila.entity.Film.inventories, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:410) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:82) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:192) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:160) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178) [spring-orm-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.jm.sakila.entity.Film.inventories, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:576) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:215) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:143) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:294) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toIterator(ForEachSupport.java:72) [jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec-1.1.2.Final.jar:1.1.2.Final]
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:66) [jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec-1.1.2.Final.jar:1.1.2.Final]
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:241) [jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec-1.1.2.Final.jar:1.1.2.Final]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.update_005finventory_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f1(update_005finventory_jsp.java:231)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.update_005finventory_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f1(update_005finventory_jsp.java:194)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.update_005finventory_jsp._jspService(update_005finventory_jsp.java:83)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:366) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    ... 86 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you post exception stack trace?

Comment: Yes, please post the exception logs.

Comment: @DavidR added full stracktrace thanks.

Comment: @premkumar added full stracktrace thanks

Comment: Having OEMIV filter configured should allow you to lazily load in view so I can only guess Filter config is not correct. It is possible the call to super.onStartup(servletContext) overwrites the newly created filter. Move this line above the call to registerOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter(servletContext);

Comment: @AlanHay My old code had super.onStartup(servletContext) on top and i still got the same error.

Comment: Well, if the filter is configured correctly it should work so I can only assume it isn't: however I am not overly familiar with this Java configuration mechanism so can't really help with that.

Comment: @AlanHay but execution sequence is first controller method gets executed and then view execution happens. as the transaction is opened and closed within controller execution(or service) , session will be closed. Now when view execution happens it will open a new transaction and the associated session will not have the entity under consideration. basically the entity under consideration is detached. therefore this problem will occur given this problem statement.

Comment: What do you think OEMIV is for? It holds the **session** open until the view is rendered allowing lazy collection fetching in the JSP. Normal transaction demarcations are respected. It does **not** start a new transaction. http://blog.jhades.org/open-session-in-view-pattern-pros-and-cons/

Comment: Any chance this entity is stored in a http session or somewhere else where you access some attributes after a first request? You will loose the hibernate session in such a case.

Comment: @AlanHay thanks for the link. as mentioned in the link, entity manager is bound to the thread at the beginning of the request. makes sense now. thank you

Comment: @Tiny this is not necessary true: you can implement your own generic OSIV Filter without any Spring dependency and *hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans* enables what is the default behavior of Eclipselink (but, you're right, I don't know about other vendors)

Comment: Is it normal that you instantiate the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` twice in `registerOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()`?

Comment: @XavierDury, was playing around with the filter. Forgot to take the first declaration out when i made the post.

Comment: Could you enable the `DEBUG` logging level for category `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` in log4j|logback|... to check that the request is correctly intercepted?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. SecurityFilter has default filter order **-100** and that is the reason. You have to put openEntityManagerInViewFilter (which order is equal to 0 or something like that) before the SecurityFilter (security filter checks user for roles and fails). Try to register filter with order=**-101**. You can use either your approach with ServletContext or the following I used (just insert in any bean marked with *@Configuration* annotation):

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean openEntityManagerInViewFilterRegistration(SecurityProperties properties) {

        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(openEntityManagerInViewFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registration.setOrder(properties.getFilterOrder()-1);
        registration.setName("openEntityManagerInViewFilter");
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean(name = "openEntityManagerInViewFilter")
    public OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter openEntityManagerInViewFilter() {
        return new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
    }
}
```

Main entry point (main class)

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
        log.info(Arrays.toString(run.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried this still doesn't work,removed all my spring security stuff as well and still same issue. Are you using FilterRegistrationBean found in the org.springframework.boot jar?   Below is the import i am using org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean

Comment: I used org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean.

Comment: I'm going to update my answer since somehow I can't post it in a comment

Comment: Not too familiar with spring boot, i assume my application has to be spring boot application for the FilterRegistrationBean to work?

Comment: Not sure about this. Where did you add my WebConfig to getServletConfigClasses or getRootConfigClasses?

Comment: i added it to getServletConfigClasses.

Comment: Have you tried to add it the root? could you please try 
 
 `public class SecurityInit extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {  
}` 
  **and** 
 
 `public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

 
 protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
  return new Class[] {WebConfig.class}; // We dont need any special servlet config yet.
 }

 
 protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
  return null;
 }

 
 protected String[] getServletMappings() {
  return new String[] {"/"};
 }
 
}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very simple.

In your jsp your are returning film from  `public Film getFilm(int filmId)`
In the jsp page you probably doing something like :

```
<jsp:getProperty name="film" property="inventories" />
```

You are trying to get invetories but it was lazy loading and session is already closed(@Transactional annotation open session and close when method is finished)

So either you will create new method to get inverntories by filmId or make it eager loading:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "film", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Inventory> inventories;
```

Comment: I already know this, to overcome the lazy load issue i used the openEntityManagerInView filter so the entity manager stays open in my views too allow the list to be accessed. But it seems the the filter isn't doing anything and not sure why?

Comment: Sorry i am not familiar with the filter functinality. I understand he should keep the session open in the view(jsp). Why not just to make it eager if you are alsways using this field? My guess the filter is wrong. What is the code of the filter?

Comment: Are you sure that the bean "entityManagerFactory" is called?

Answer (score 0):

Transaction was completed before JSP is rendered and hence Hibernate Session is no longer available for lazily loading the said property.

Alternative solution (which does not require the use of the OEMIV filter): if you wish to retain lazy loading for the said collection property elsewhere in your code, create a separate finder method `findFilmWithInventories` for retrieving the entity and do a `join fetch` query to eagerly load the said collection.

Comment: This in in another incorrect answer given the User is Trying to Use the Open Entity Manager in View Pattern.

Comment: If you read carefully the OP attempted to solve the issue through the use of the said filter. Posting alternative solutions does not constitute an "incorrect answer".

Comment: if he is trying to use OEMIV I guess he is aware that that the session is by default no longer available when JSP is rendered. A correct answer would be to tell him why the filter is not working.

Comment: The underlying issue is that lazy loading don't work. If the OP wishes to continue working around the issue with OEMIV, I'm fine with that. But if he chooses to explore other ways of solving the issue then my answer may help him. Merry Christmas.

Comment: The OP problem is to lazy load entities outside transaction, and OSIV is just a workaround, not the problem itself. So, IMO, this answer is totally acceptable and a downvote is not appropriate. +1 to compensate :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, in this case, it's *much more simple* to abandon *OpenSessionInView/OpenEntityManagerInView*, and use

```
<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />
```

in persistence.xml (or configure it programmatically).

This property has a similar behavior (and pros/cons) of OSIV, except that a new EntityManager can potentially be instantiated on each lazy load trigger, instead of having a lone and long scoped one, so you have to be aware of it to properly manage the persistence context(s).

However, this never fails with *no Session*.

Comment: I would strongly advice against using that feature of Hibernate. A new EntityManager automatically created to load unfetched lazy associations means no first-level cache between those requests. You could easily end up navigating an object graph where, navigating through two distinct paths to the same database object you could end up with two different instances of the same object. Let's suppose you're going to change that logical object and you want to merge it back to the db. Hibernate will refuse to merge it as it will find two separate object instances for the same logical entity.

Comment: And I didn't even mention that you'd have no transaction isolation at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I disagree. You shouldn't advice against some feature in an absolute manner. Since we are speaking about OSIV probably the OP is already used to manage **detached** entities (and different instances of the same entity too). As for Transaction Isolation I don't see the problem, since *enable_lazy_load_no_trans* is about lazy loading **without** using a transaction.

Comment: It's not the detached objects that create the problem. The problem is that this solution actually changes the in-memory representation of an object graph loaded in a previous transaction without the usual reference-integrity guarantees that the first-level cache of JPA solutions provide. And without any transaction isolation guarantees either.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `film.getInventories()` somewhere inside your `@Transactional` service layer. This give you more control instead of eager loading on JPA level:

```
@Service
public class FilmService {

   @Autowired
   private FilmDao filmDao;

   @Transactional
    public Film getFilm(int filmId, boolean loadInventories) {
        Film film = filmDao.getFilm(filmId);
        if(loadInventories){ film.getInventories(); }
        return film;
    }
}
```

Since it would need another round-trip to DB i would recommend to add some caching.

You can also add generic field loading functionality like this:

```
   @Transactional
    public Film getFilm(int filmId, String[] propertiesToLoad) {
        Film film = filmDao.getFilm(filmId);
        BeanWrapper bw = new BeanWrapperImpl(item);
        for (String propertyName : propertiesToLoad) {
           bw.getPropertyValue(propertyName);
        }
        return film;
    }
```